# Postgresql hierarchical (tree) query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I found few topics about it but none fits my expected results.
I have levels of categories stored in the table, just want to display it as tree structure.
All answers are kind of following query:

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=58c47486cbf7f65d9757ee9632c4c0db)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_category, 1 AS level
   FROM   category
   WHERE level = 1
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, ct.level + 1
   FROM   cte ct
   JOIN   category c ON c.parent_category = ct.category_id
   )
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

But the results are like

```
level
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

What I want to achieve is

```
level
1
2
3
3
2
3
3
1
2
3
3
2
3
3
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for your ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically keek track of the path to each node and use that for ordering. In Postgres, arrays come handy for this:

```
with recursive cte as (
   select category_id, category_name, parent_category, 1 as level, array[category_id] path
   from category
   where parent_category is null
   union all
   select c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, ct.level + 1, ct.path || c.category_id
   from cte ct
   join category c on c.parent_category = ct.category_id
)
select *
from cte
order by path
```

Note that there is no need to store the `level` in the table; you can compute the information on the fly as you iterate. To identify the root nodes, you can filter on rows whose parent is `null`.

In [your db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b1a2cf1eeb598f70cbaf3bafe6de63a1), the query returns:

```
category_id | category_name | parent_category | level | path    
----------: | :------------ | --------------: | ----: | :-------
          1 | cat1          |            null |     1 | {1}     
          3 | cat3          |               1 |     2 | {1,3}   
          8 | cat8          |               3 |     3 | {1,3,8} 
          9 | cat9          |               3 |     3 | {1,3,9} 
          4 | cat4          |               1 |     2 | {1,4}   
          6 | cat6          |               4 |     3 | {1,4,6} 
          7 | cat7          |               4 |     3 | {1,4,7} 
          5 | cat5          |               1 |     2 | {1,5}   
         10 | cat10         |               5 |     3 | {1,5,10}
         11 | cat11         |               5 |     3 | {1,5,11}
          2 | cat2          |            null |     1 | {2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the hierarchy as an array and use that for ordering:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
     SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_category, 1 AS level, array[category_id] as categories
     FROM category
     WHERE level = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, ct.level + 1, ct.categories || c.category_id
     FROM cte ct JOIN
          category c
          ON c.parent_category = ct.category_id
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY categories;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8cf1152f244400f44ddfcd0744784ed9) is a db<>fiddle.